# Optimization of heavy view hierarchy

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have 4 screens where user can swipe between. I use ViewPager and inflate ViewGroup in `instantiateItem()`. Everything is perfect if all childs of ViewGroups are *lightweight*, but when background and couple images added on each of screens the swipe animation becomes jerky.

The first thing I did to optimize it is making snapshot of view hierarchy and replacing the whole view hierarchy with single ImageView displaying snapshot. It performs good, and swipe is smooth, but on some devices it causes `OutOfMemoryError`.

I believe the problem is that ViewPager loads current, `idx+1` and `idx-1` pages, and if display is for example `1920 x 1200px` (Asus Transformer TF700), and each px supports transparency, then `1920x1200x4 = 9MB` for each page, and if 3 pages are loaded then `9x3 = 27MB`, it is > `16MB` (heap limit), and `OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown.

How can I show these 4 pages without causing the Error and make swipe smooth at the same time?

Comment: can u use nine patch images if possible? low in size can expand to meet all devices

Comment: It probably has to do with the images being too big?  Where exactly is the OutOfMemoryError occuring?  Is it during a call to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` perhaps?  I would look into using a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to help with that.

Comment: @AtulOHolic, I need to show intro, every page contains around 6-7 images=~250KB (all come from drawables). I use 9patch for 1 button. If I don't do snapshots, then no memory issues, but animation is jerky.

Comment: @user1199931, the Error occuring at LayoutInflater.inflate().

Comment: If the images are only for intro then may be try creating them as a page separately and use them as an html file or something at least you can avoid the drawables. I am not sure what exactly the scenario is for you. May be I may sound dumb. Pardon me for that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered populating the images from the java program using BitmapFactory.decodeResource (Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
and setting opts.inSampleSize to a value > 1?

This should provide a lighter image hence consuming less memory.

Comment: It makes bitmaps really horrible, much better results with Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(). Hey! Maybe I should use a 2D engine (gaming) to draw my textures? It's written on c++ and should manage memory more carefully.